# Sperner's Lemma/Intermediate Value Theorem - odd number of crossings counting multiplicity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics

Suppose $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is not just continuous, but also smooth. Let $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$. Is it true that the graph of $f$ crosses the $x$-axis an odd number of times, counting multiplicity (so at tangency points, you perform derivatives repeatedly)?

**Motivation:** I was reading about [Sperner's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma#One-dimensional_case) for 1-dimension, which I can use to show the IVT. But Sperner's Lemma also talks about an odd number of color switches, and on first sight, it seems plausible that the IVT should also hold with odd number of intersections. Of course, this is not true given that you can just "touch" the axis and cause there to be an even number of intersections. But touching suggests that counting multiplicity may solve the problem. Multiplicity can only be properly defined with smooth functions, and hence the hypothesis of "smooth" rather than "continuous".

**Edit:** If smooth + multiplicity is problematic, is there some way to fix the situation?

Comment: You can have a genuine crossing where all higher order derivatives are 0 so your idea of multiplicity won't work. What you really need is *transversality*, which says in this case that the derivative is nonzero at all intersection points.

Comment: Also, what is the multiplicity of the root of $sign(x)\sqrt{|x|}$? To define multiplicity, you need to be able to find a Taylor polynomial that has one non-zero coefficient. This of course is given if you restrict your reasoning to polynomials.